# Select only one single RadioButton in RadGrid with Paging and any PageSize at Server Side Code behind in C# ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik

Check / Select only one single Radio Button in Rad Grid or Grid View with Paging and any PageSize at Server Side Code behind in C#

My Aim is to maintain user selected asp:RadioButton inside telerik:RadGrid to be selected / checked even with the paging of the grid and with any PageSize accordingly.

The Challenges i'm facing are unable to maintain Unique GroupName for each RadioButton present for each row in Grid. Due to this i have to handle this functionality in code behind.

How ever i tried searching internet for solution which i found some javascript answers with lot of work around which i'm not satisfied with them.

```
<telerik:RadGrid ID="rgWithPaging" AllowPaging="True" CellSpacing="0" GridLines="None"
                AllowSorting="True" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                AllowFilteringByColumn="true" EnableLinqExpressions="false"
                PagerStyle-PageSizeControlType="RadDropDownList" PagerStyle-AlwaysVisible="true" Visible="true"
                OnNeedDataSource="rgWithPaging_NeedDataSource">
...........
    <telerik:GridTemplateColumn HeaderText="Check One" HeaderStyle-CssClass="gradient" AllowFiltering="false" HeaderStyle-Width="10%">
     <ItemTemplate>
      <asp:RadioButton ID="rbWPFileName" runat="server"/>
     </ItemTemplate>
    </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
...........
</telerik:RadGrid>
```

Comment: Okay Grant Winney i'm new here, thanks for suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Answer i came up with server side code behind is as given below:

```
<telerik:RadGrid ID="rgWithPaging" AllowPaging="True" CellSpacing="0" GridLines="None"
                AllowSorting="True" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                AllowFilteringByColumn="true" EnableLinqExpressions="false"
                PagerStyle-PageSizeControlType="RadDropDownList" PagerStyle-AlwaysVisible="true" Visible="true"
                OnNeedDataSource="rgWithPaging_NeedDataSource" OnDataBound="rgWithPaging_OnDataBound">
...........
    <telerik:GridTemplateColumn HeaderText="Check One" HeaderStyle-CssClass="gradient" AllowFiltering="false" HeaderStyle-Width="10%">
     <ItemTemplate>
      <asp:RadioButton ID="rbWPFileName" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="rbWPFileName_OnCheckedChanged"/>
     </ItemTemplate>
    </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
...........
</telerik:RadGrid>
```

now in code behind to achieve this we need only two events

> **OnCheckedChanged="rbWPFileName_OnCheckedChanged" and 
>   OnDataBound="rgWithPaging_OnDataBound"**

In code behind:

```
    protected void rbWPFileName_OnCheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var rbtnSelected = sender as RadioButton;
            if (rbtnSelected == null) return;
            foreach (GridDataItem item in rgWithPaging.Items)
            {
                var radFileName = (RadioButton)item.FindControl("rbWPFileName");
                if (radFileName == null) return; 
                radFileName.Checked = rbtnSelected.ClientID == radFileName.ClientID;
                if (radFileName.Checked)
                {
                    var position = (rgWithPaging.PageSize*rgWithPaging.CurrentPageIndex) + item.ItemIndex;
                    Session["Position"] = position;
                }
            }
        }

protected void rgWithPaging_OnDataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Session["Position"] == null) return;
        var position = (int)Session["Position"];
        var pageIndex = position / rgWithPaging.PageSize;
        var itemIndex = position%rgWithPaging.PageSize;

        if (pageIndex == rgWithPaging.CurrentPageIndex)
        {
            foreach (GridDataItem item in rgWithPaging.Items)
            {
                var radFileName = (RadioButton)item.FindControl("rbWPFileName");
                if (radFileName == null) return;
                radFileName.Checked = itemIndex == item.ItemIndex;
            }
        }
    }
```

that's it task done!!!  enjoy..:-)